# How to display a bitmap as background of view without stretching android

Tags: android, view, bitmap, scaling

I want to set a bitmap as a view background without stretching and i dnt want to change the view width and height as wrap-content. I want to keep the width and height of view as match-parent. I have set background of view like below, where mDrawingView is a custom view which extends View.

```
 Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(copy.getAbsolutePath());
 mDrawingView.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), tempBitmap));
```

and my layout file looks like below,

```
  <MyPackageName.DrawingView
            android:id="@+id/drawing_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/white"/>
```

And please note I'm not using imageview.

Please suggest  me any idea?

Comment: Please, [check documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) on the scales available by default. Realize that either your View will increase, or will not use the full area inside, when drawing different shapes, in different canvas (a square cannot fully fill a circle, etc).

Comment: `backgrounds` are scaled to fill the View anyway. Therefore, the'll be stretched if the View (much likely) doesn't have the same aspect ratio than the background. I think you might want to use a **9 patch**, instead.

Comment: In my case I have pick image from gallery dynamically. Its not a static image @BobMalooga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed my DrawingView which extends Imageview instead of View and then set the bitmap like below

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(copy.getAbsolutePath());
  mDrawingView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Now bitmap displays on imageview without stretching and works perfect.

Thanks for your valuable comments and answers.

Comment: How do you do this if the view is not an ImageView?

Answer (score 0):

**if your are using image view then** you can do like below

```
 ImageView.ScaleType
```

which can be CenterCrop,fit etc you can read about it here it's android native support
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.res_id);
```

where `res_id` is the resource id in drawable folder.